# How to make a responsive page fit portrait mode on page load for Android

Tags: android-layout, responsive-design, landscape-portrait

I'm trying to make a responsive design work for portrait mode on an android tablet. The issue I'm getting is it doesn't load to fit the page of portrait mode. It loads a larger size of the width and then when I switch to landscape it fits correctly. Then when I switch back to portrait I get a zoomed out version that fits the page. Here is a basic example of what I mean http://playground.fameordie.com. How can I make this page load to fit portrait mode keeping the aspect of the actual page?

Comment: do you want fix screen to portrait mode ?

Comment: @iDroid Explorer I want the page to load to fit bot L and P keeping the same aspect. Like youtube videos on a tab. The menu keeps its same aspect as where my page loads beyond the width in portrait and only fits after brought back in a zoomed out version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following to the

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

If you want users to be able to double tap to zoom (recommended) then omit the maximum-scale item

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```